ClickHouse - Unable to count the total number of rows in a table and paginate when using the MongoDB Engine
1. Describe the unexpected behaviour
I am using ClickHouse version 24.6.3.95 and MongoDB versions 6.0.11 and 4.4.29-28. I also tried upgrading ClickHouse to the latest version24.8.3.59. I have a collection in MongoDB with approximately 200,000 docs. I am using the MongoDB engine to create a table in ClickHouse. When querying the ClickHouse table just created, I encounter the following three issues:
I can only query data from 0 to 101. When querying from 0 to 102, it results in a timeout. After encountering this error, querying again from 0 to 101 will also result in a timeout.
When I use SELECT COUNT(*) FROM remote_table_mongo;, it results in a timeout.
Due to errors (1) and (2), I am unable to paginate.
I tested a table with 700 docs, and everything worked fine. Do you have any solutions for me? Thank you.
2. Detail
A. Testing with Two Tables
I tested with 2 tables as follows: TABLE_NAME_1 (10,693 docs) and TABLE_NAME_2 (391,091 docs).

For table TABLE_NAME_1:

First query:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME_1 LIMIT 0,101;

=> rows_before_limit_at_least: 101
Second query:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME_1 LIMIT 0,102;

=> rows_before_limit_at_least: 10,693


For table TABLE_NAME_2:

First query:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME_2 LIMIT 0,101;

=> rows_before_limit_at_least: 101
Second query:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME_2 LIMIT 0,102;

=> Timeout error



=> I think the issue is related to how ClickHouse handles the rows_before_limit_at_least value.
B. Issues with Counting Total Rows

When I run:

Query:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME_1;


Response:
10,693


When I run:

Query:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME_2;


Response:
Timeout error



Can count and paginate when selecting

Why do you use engine=MongoDB
instead connect to mongodb directly without clickhouse?
engine=MongoDB is a proxy engine, only WHERE filters could be applied
other SQL operations like ORDER BY / GROUP BY / LIMIT calculated on clickhouse-server side after load data from mongo into local memory of clickhouse-server process

I see that ClickHouse supports the MongoDB Engine, so I want to try using it. But is the issue with pagination and counting the number of records when using the MongoDB Engine due to limitations of ClickHouse, or am I doing something wrong?

read my comment, again
yep, this is clickhouse engine=MongoDb limitation
